# Is there a injective compact operator $T$ such that #$sp(T) < \infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $X$ a Banach spaces such that $\dim X = \infty$, and $T: X\to X$ a injective compact operator. Is there $T$ such that #$sp(T) < \infty$  ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by # -- the cardinality of a set?

Comment: Cardinality of spectrum of $T$. In this case, when the spectrum is finite

Comment: So obviously you are interested in an infinite dimensional case, no? You should be more careful when writing questions. I mean, if $X,Y$ are finite dimensional, then the question is simply not interesting.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  There are injective compact quasinilpotent operators (having spectrum $\{0\}$).  For example, on a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_0,e_1,\ldots\}$, let $T$ be the continuous linear extension of $e_n\mapsto \frac{1}{n+1}e_{n+1}$.  Then $T$ is compact and injective, and the spectrum of $T$ is $\{0\}$.